# How do I run something at the end of the current runloop?

Tags: ember.js

I want to defer an operation until all bindings have flushed and the current runloop has finished. How do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Ember.run.schedule](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_schedule) method:

```
 Ember.run.schedule(queue[, context], callback[, *args]);
```

Here, `queue` is the run-loop queue (e.g. `'actions'`), and `callback` is the function you want executed. For example:

```
 Ember.run.schedule('actions', function() {
   console.log('I run at the end of the current runloop');
 });
```

Relatedly, to prevent the function from running multiple times, use [Ember.run.once](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_once) (you may have also seen it referred to as `scheduleOnce`):

```
 Ember.run.once([context,] callback[, *args]);
```

This will run the callback in the `'actions'` queue.

(Updated; thanks to @machty for the corrections!)

Comment: I think the terminology here is a little vague... in the RunLoop architecture, there's the code you write that goes between `begin` and `end`, and then all of the internal run loop code for flushing out all the actions scheduled. To me, it makes more sense to refer to the post-`end` flushing phase as the run loop, since it takes what you just ran, and loops over the scheduled actions over and over again til the queues are flushed.

Comment: If we're both using the same terminology, I don't think Ember.run.schedule necessary defers an operation until after all the bindings have flushed (which happens to take place in the `sync`) queue; rather, it merely schedules the operation to take place _during_ the current run loop, along with all the other binding sync-ups and so on. If you particularly want something to happen after the bindings have sync'd, you'd have to specify a queue that came after `sync`, such as `action`. But I'm still new to a lot of this too so I could be getting something wrong.

Comment: Re terminology, the [Ember.run API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_begin) seem to call the whole thing a "RunLoop", not just the end. Re queues, you are quite right about that. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-metal/lib/run_loop.js), I'm not sure what the default behavior is if you don't specify a queue name

Comment: I looked into it a bit more; `Ember.run.schedule` needs its queue argument specified, so I think your example above needs to be corrected. If you want the bindings to be sync'd up by the time you run your callback, you should specify 'actions' as the queue, which is the queue right after 'sync' (which resolves the bindings). So, `Ember.run.schedule('actions', function() {});` would work. The `context` arg is optional though (since their could internally makes use of `invoke` function, which lets you specify a callback and optionally specify a context)

Comment: Note that your usage of `Ember.run.once` is correct though; it will always schedule on the 'actions' queue after the bindings have resolved.